# Sublime Text 3 'subl' command still linked to Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

This is driving me crazy. I'm running OSX and until today I had Sublime Text 2 installed. After installing Sublime Text 3, when I enter the 'subl' command the terminal logs:

```
Unable to find application named 'Sublime Text 2'
```

I've tried everything. I've tried

```
$ rm ~/bin/subl
```

Then

```
$ ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ~/bin/subl
```

I've also tried going in to usr directly and removing the subl command. When I do this, the subl command will sometimes work while I remain in one directory, but once I switch directories it goes back to giving me the message

```
Unable to find application named 'Sublime Text 2'
```

With Sublime Text 2 I had subl entered as an alias. I also tried going in and unaliasing subl like this:

```
unalias subl
```

And I've tried re-creating the alias using

```
/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Again, this will work for a while, but once I change directories it stops working.

Any advice on what to try next? I'm at a loss. I can't understand why it works for a while, then stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `.bashrc` file, and `.bash_profile` and see if it's aliased in there. Both of these are in your home directory `~`.

`nano ~/.bashrc`

`nano ~/.bash_profile`

No need to sudo as you own these documents.

Comment: No problem @metropolis4, I just learned this a few week ago after taking apart [Paul Irish's `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`](https://github.com/allouis/dotfiles-paulirish). It's a wonderful world when to dive in head first. I made a [Sublime Text Twilight Inspired Terminal Theme](https://github.com/Dygear/Backup) for the Mac OSX Terminal. I think it's pretty awesome, but I'm bias because I made it.

Comment: @MarkTomlin is the first link forked somewhere?

Comment: @greyxray Paul Irish's [`.bash_profile`](https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile) & [`.bash_prompt`](https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_prompt) from his GitHub.